# Linux kernel modules with no __init function

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I'm reading through the book Linux Device Drivers, by Corbet, Rubini & Kroah-Hartman,
p.31 "The use of module_init is mandatory." This is all well and good but when I look at the source code for drivers, say for example the ones for nfc, specifically:

https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/drivers/nfc/st95hf/core.c.html

I don't see the __init function. And then doing a search through the rest of the drivers there are very few that actually use this function. So why is that, what am I missing?

Comment: Given module uses the macro `module_spi_driver`, which replaces `module_init`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/include/linux/spi/spi.h#L215.

Comment: aaaah, thank you so much